# isinstance file python 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: python

In Python 2.7 I get the following results:

```
>>> with open("README.md", "r") as fin:
...     print(isinstance(fin, file))
... 
True
```

In python 3.5 I get:

```
>>> with open("README.md", "r") as fin:
...     print(isinstance(fin, file))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

So, OK I look at the Python docs and find out that in Python 3.5, files are of type `io.IOBase` (or some subclass). Leading me to this:

```
>>> import io
>>> with open("README.md", "r") as fin:
...     print(isinstance(fin, io.IOBase))
... 
True
```

But then when I try in Python 2.7:

```
>>> import io
>>> with open("README.md", "r") as fin:
...     print(isinstance(fin, io.IOBase))
... 
False
```

So at this point, I'm confused. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase), I feel as though Python 2.7 should report `True`.

Obviously I'm missing something elementary, perhaps because it's 6:30 PM ET, but I have two related questions:

1. Why does Python report `False` for `isinstance(fin, io.IOBase)`?
2. Is there a way to test that a variable is an open file which will work in both Python 2.7 and 3.5?

Comment: "Under Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the built-in file object", so not the same in 2.x.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a link so I can read more, do you?

Comment: It's at the top of the page you linked.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the linked documentation:

> Under Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the built-in file object

So they are not the same in python 2.x.

As to part 2, this works in python2 and 3, though not the prettiest thing in the world:

```
import io
try:
    file_types = (file, io.IOBase)

except NameError:
    file_types = (io.IOBase,)

with open("README.md", "r") as fin:
    print(isinstance(fin, file_types))
```

Comment: Since it's just for `isinstance` checks, you don't need the `tuple` wrapping in the Py3 case; just `file_types = io.IOBase` would work (possibly slightly more efficiently).

Comment: @ShadowRanger aye, but kept it for consistency + the name of the variable indicates a sequence. Not that keen on optimizing such stuff unless really needed.

Comment: OK, so I'm marking this answer as correct because I feel it's the correct answer to my question, but since my ultimate goal is to have a Python 2.7 and 3.5 compatible code base, I'm actually switching my `open()` calls to `io.open()` calls which work in both versions and you can test them the same way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @iLoveTux using io.open has the added benefit of `encoding=...`, `newline=...` support in Py2 too.

Comment: @IIja, awesome! I'm sure that making this change will ultimately lead to more compatible code and it's just one more import and three more keystrokes per file. I can't believe I couldn't find anything online about this before. I'm just now getting into Python 3, so I'm sure there is a lot more to learn. Anyway, thank you for everything, including the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

For python2

```
import types
f = open('test.txt', 'r')   # assuming this file exists
print (isinstance(f,types.FileType))
```

For python3

```
import io
import types
f1 = open('test.txt', 'r')   # assuming this file exists
f2 = open('test.txt', 'rb')   # assuming this file exists
print (isinstance(f1,io.IOBase))
print (isinstance(f2,io.IOBase))
```

(Edit: my previous solution tested for io.TextIOWrapper, it worked only with files opened in text mode.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy which describes the python3 class hierarchy).

Comment: in Python 3.5, I get `AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'FileType'`

Comment: You are right (see my edit).  The `types` module in python3  is completely different.

Comment: `isinstance(open('testi.txt', 'rb'), io.TextIOWrapper) == False`. Use the Base, Luke ... @SciProg